# What is the operator %%=%% in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I haven't managed to find an entire valid query using it, but I have reasonable evidence (primarily code to handle it in internal code to analyze queries) that there are some situations where `%%=%%` is a valid operator in T-SQL.

A simple query like `select * from a where b %%=%% c` is not valid when `a` is a table with int columns `b` and `c`, so if it is ever valid it's a more complex setup than just a table with a couple of in columns.

It doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, although searching for `%%=%%` is quite hard, all the search engines I've tried just ignore it even if it's in quotes.

Comment: Can you provide a valid usage for it? [Googling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="%25%25%3D%25%25"+SQL) literally gives nothing.

Comment: No, haven't found a valid usage of it yet, just the test case `select * from a where b %%=%% c` in tests for our T-SQL parser, and some code to handle `%%=%%` in code that analyzed real queries from a database. Unfortunately git history gives no clues as to what prompted those test cases/code to be added.

Comment: It certainly feels like some external parser instruction (dynamic comparison operators?) rather than tsql.

Comment: `reasonable evidence` post it. I've worked with SQL Server for 25 years and never seen this

Comment: Well, it's reasonable evidence to me :) in that I trust my fellow devs not to add test cases and code to handle an operator that they never encountered for real. The code to analyze queries will have been dealing with the output of sys.dm_exec_sql_text from a real database, unfortunately the application that produced the query that has been replaced so we no longer have the original query :(

Comment: If you trust them so much, why not ask them then? Surely they know what the syntax is.

Comment: The test case was added prior to 2009 and before the beginning of the source code history, so I don't know which individual added it, and even if I did I doubt they'd still be at the company. As for the query analyzer, the person who added the code to handle it recalls encountering that operator in a query, and having to add the workaround, but no longer has a copy of the query. They have no idea what the syntax is, and never did, just that it appeared in a query run against a database.

Comment: Well, as has been mentioned, that syntax is not valid T-SQL (or even SQL) syntax, @MarkRaymond . so if it is there to analyse code, it would be given false positives; T-SQL that contains that syntax would error as you have seen.

Comment: I've never seen this syntax.

Comment: If this is an operator in any context (which is *just about* possible, as there is a small handful of constructs that are valid only in system stored procedures that are otherwise not valid T-SQL), it is definitely undocumented and unsupported in user code, and there probably shouldn't be any tests for it. Even if a parser had to deal with encountering internal system syntax in the wild, it should be distinguishing that based on the connection properties and ignore it, and not attempt to make a valid parse. (Also, this is why tests should always be done against actual, reproducible cases...)

Comment: Never seen that in any SQL server but I remembers me something... Back in 2007 while working within IIS asp and DAO and limited resources, especially RAM since it was a lot faster to replace a string than making a prepare with parameters/variables after several attempts I decided that things like %PAR1% were good as placeholder to pass to a custom parse / replacement function which gave out the SQL syntax. 
In my case I used it with a name and a single % but it could work easily like that with the same purpose of injecting / changing something in a SQL string command.

Comment: Possibly confusing with the undocumented `%%physloc%%` row locator?

Comment: Haha, it's actually while trying to implement support for the undocumented `%%lockres%%` column that we uncovered the test case for `%%=%%` operator!